# Is posting a form with jquery ajax faster than normal html post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to post a form and then reload it with the fields cleard i am using codeigniter and my problem is that the post process takes about 1 second to complete. My question is it faster if i use jquery ajax?

I know one second is not much but in this case i need it faster so that i can insert another value fast.

Comment: Nope speed is no where in picture in both case. thing is with or without page refresh. save full network call and extra burden to server via request response method.

Comment: The AJAX post will be perceived as being quicker.  The time it takes the post to go to the server and back to the client, and of course the processing time on the server won't change. But as other comment alludes to the overhead from rendering the full page will be mitigated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no because AJAX only lets you avoid reloading most of the page (images, scripts and styles) but the AJAX request and response won't be any faster.

**SOMETHING TO CONSIDER:**
This might not be an option for you since I am assuming you wouldn't want to switch development environment to one such as MEAN that leverages JavaScript to improve request and response time and also development.